# Error while checking the jupyter notebook on the web browser using an AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, jupyter-notebook

When i run the jupyter notebook it successfully runs it on the command prompt and displays the message that the jupyter notebook is running at

```
The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
https://(ip-172-31-37-171 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=9b00453fd4f9692418873e9d988013f250116bbb94277e74
```

However when I check web browser I just does not load and the command prompt window displays the following. Any help would highly appreciated

[image: Command prompt message as soon as I try checking the web browser]

Google chrome displays the below message

[image: Chrome web browser message]

Answer (score 0):

I think your are running the Jupiter notebook with SSL enabled. You might also probably using self signed certificate.

You can try to run the server with SSL disabled, and if you want to enable SSL, you could do it easily through a load balancer.

Comment: if you are following some guidelines to setup, share it with the question, i could have a look.